# Nylon bag vs plastic bag

Tags: american-english, phrase-usage

I was buying some carry out and I asked for a nylon bag. The cashier, who is not a native speaker, gave me a look and offered a 'plastic bag', which is what I wanted to begin with.

I don't know why I used "nylon" instead of "plastic"; I'm not a native speaker but I'm fluent in English and that got me thinking:

Is there any difference between "nylon bag" and "plastic bag"? Can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: Can you provide a picture of what you would call a *nylon bag*? It's not a term that would be used with takeout food in the U.S.

Comment: I don't know what one would call a "nylon bag"; what I meant in that particular conversation is a typical "plastic shopping bag", like this one https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/Hemdchentuete.jpg (even though that is a fancy one)

Comment: I'm no materials scientist, but I'd be pretty sure the type of plastic used to make "disposable" bags (from supermarkets, etc.) isn't "nylon".

Comment: You'd know better, @FumbleFingers, if you'd lived through the 70's as a teen in the US and had a clinging, sweat-trapping, yet fashionable plastic windbreaker jacket vs. a comfortable, breathable nylon windbreaker! :-)

Comment: @Kristina: I was a teen in the *60s*. And I really *hated* nylon shirts (and sheets too! :)

Comment: *Nylon* is a specific type of plastic -- the plastic used to make the thread in "Nylon" hosiery.  It is occasionally used as the plastic in "sorta hard" plastic things -- perhaps some of the plastic snap-lid containers you might buy to store food in the fridge -- but has never, to my knowledge, been used to make "plastic bags".  The plastic in "plastic bags" is traditionally *polyethylene* (often called "polly"), though I suspect that other plastics are used as well.

Comment: nylon is a strong type of plastic used for making ropes; I believe the plastic used for shopping bags is called polythene

Comment: To be pedantic "Nylon" is the brand name invented by DuPont for the family of aliphatic polyamides invented in 1935 as a silk substitute.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, they can't be used interchangeably (in the US) since nylon bags and plastic store-purchase-type bags are different materials entirely.

**Nylon bag (typically called a laundry bag)**

[image: Nylon bag from anypromo.com typically called a laundry bag]

**Plastic shopping bag**

[image: Plastic bag from uline.com]

Edit: and to Aml's point, nylon is a synthetic woven fiber and plastic is not.

Comment: In my native language there is no distinction between the two (at least in informal use, I'm sure scientists differentiate) so I conflated them as well.

Comment: That's interesting ventsyv, which is why I think this question shouldn't be closed.  We're both English speakers yet the same word, in common use, means different things to us.  I feel smarter now! :-)

Comment: All nylon is plastic, not all plastic is nylon.

Comment: _Nylon_ is polysemic; (a) it is the name for one of a set of related polymers; (b) it is the name for the woven material often made from these.

Comment: A "(disposable) plastic shopping bag" is usually made out of LDPE (low-density polyethylene) film. I'm not quite sure why, but LDPE isn't usually made into fibers, though UHMWPE (ultra-high molecular weight polyethylene) is with trade-names Dyneema/Spectra.

Comment: Quite right @NickT, and according to our good friend (kidding!) Wikipedia: Polyethylene (abbreviated PE) or polyethene (IUPAC name polyethene or poly(methylene)) is the most common plastic. The annual global production is around 80 million tonnes. Its primary use is in packaging (plastic bags, plastic films, geomembranes, containers including bottles, etc.).

Comment: @NickT: The main difference is stretchability. Low density PET stretches but high density PET is stretch resistant. There are cloth made of low density PET: polyester (note: polyester is a blanket term so they're not all PET, but the cheap disco shirts of the 60s is made of the same type of plastic as shopping bags).

Comment: @NickT "but LDPE isn't usually made into fibers" [really](https://www.indiamart.com/gulshan-plastic/industrial-plastic-rope.html)?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Nylon is a plastic, but the lightweight plastic bags they give you at stores are not nylon.  Nylon works well as a fiber, so a 'nylon' bag could refer to a woven bag, such as are re-used instead of re-cycled.  {And I don't think it was construed as requesting a bag for nylon stockings.}

Comment: Nylon is a plastic but not all plastic are nylon. Similarly, not all woven plastic are nylon - some are polyester or microfiber or rayon or dacron (which ironically is the same type of plastic as plastic bags). Also, not all nylon are fibres. Nylon is commonly used as plastic ball bearings and washers due to it's low friction. Toys typically use nylon bearings